# Catchable fatal error: Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to string in

Tags: php, mysqli, verifyerror

i want create verify page from my ebank, e bank send bellow parameters  :

```
$Status = $_POST['status'];
$Refnumber = $_POST['refnumber'];
$Resnumber = $_POST['resnumber'];
        $res = $client->VerifyPayment(array("MerchantID" => $MerchantID , "Password" =>$Password , "Price" =>$Price,"RefNum" =>$Refnumber ));
$Status = $res->verifyPaymentResult->ResultStatus;
$PayPrice = $res->verifyPaymentResult->PayementedPrice;
```

i want add Amount to user data base with bellow code :

```
    $MerchantID = 'xxxxx';
$Password = 'xxxxx';




if(isset($_POST['status']) && $_POST['status'] == 100){



    $Status = $_POST['status'];
    $Refnumber = $_POST['refnumber'];
    $Resnumber = $_POST['resnumber'];
    $price = $db2->query("SELECT `price` FROM `user_payments`  WHERE `invoice_number` = '$Resnumber'");

    $client = new SoapClient('http://merchant.parspal.com/WebService.asmx?wsdl');       
    $res = $client->VerifyPayment(array("MerchantID" => $MerchantID , "Password" =>$Password , "Price" =>$Price,"RefNum" =>$Refnumber ));
    $Status = $res->verifyPaymentResult->ResultStatus;
    $PayPrice = $res->verifyPaymentResult->PayementedPrice;

    $db2->query("UPDATE `user_payments` SET `done` = '1' , `refid` = '$Refnumber' WHERE `invoice_number` = '$Resnumber'");
    $new_balance = $this->user->info->balance + $PayPrice;
    $uid = $this->user->info->id;
    $fee = $PayPrice;
    $time = time();
    $db2->query("UPDATE `users` SET `balance` = '$new_balance' WHERE `id` = '$uid' ");
    $db2->query("INSERT INTO `user_balance_report` (`uid`,`type`,`fee`,`msg`,`date`)VALUES('$uid','3','+".$fee."','your code: ".$Resnumber."','$time')");
    $D->user_purchase = "success <br>cost $fee Added in your account.";
    $this->user->sess['LOGGED_USER'] = $this->network->get_user_by_id($this->user->id, TRUE);
    $this->user->info = & $this->user->sess['LOGGED_USER'];
    }
```

but i have see this code when back from bank : 
Catchable fatal error: Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to string in this line :

```
        $res = $client->VerifyPayment(array("MerchantID" => $MerchantID , "Password" =>$Password , "Price" =>$Price,"RefNum" =>$Refnumber ));
```

Comment: Your price variable is an mysql dataset object, extract price as string from it and you'll be good

Comment: can you explain me more please ? how can i ? :)

Comment: Not sure what kind of class you use to handle your db operations, but usually you get a set of objects/arrays with each one of those looking like `array('id' => 1, 'price' => 9.99)`, by executing `->query()`, so you just need to extract that. Make sense?

Comment: [See an example](http://us3.php.net/mysqli_fetch_assoc)

Comment: i used :
 $price = $db2->query("SELECT `price` FROM `user_payments`  WHERE `invoice_number` = '$Resnumber'");
and fix  with : 
 $price = $db2->fetch_field


thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i should be used

```
$price = $db2->fetch_field("SELECT `price` FROM `user_payments`  WHERE `invoice_number` = '$Resnumber'");
```